# Excel format numbers so there is space after second number

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I am working with 5 and 6 digit numbers, 2 + 3(4) (maybe +5 in the future, like 22 123 or 22 1234). I must write these numbers without space and want it to be formated with space. Simple enough, I thought, but no.

I tried a lot of combinations like `## ####`, `00" 0000"`, `##_*`, `##__####`(basically I tried to combine variations of #, *, ", 0) but nothing works for both. It's either:

```
22 123 and 221 234
```

or

```
2 2123 and 22 1234
```

(or just total mess).

Comment: Is it possible to create different custom number formats separately, ## ### and ## ####?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format in the Custom field (for +3 & +4):

```
[<=99999]##_####;##_#####
```

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code.

```
00 #####
```

It could have all "#" characters if preferred. I see you show that as not working, but either only fails to work when there are less than the stated number of characters.

For example, "221" leads to "00 221" as shown, or "221" with all "#" in the format code. However, this is due to there not being the stated number of characters, not due to the format being wrong.

If you need a failure-tolerant code, then you must give up on the idea that they will always fit your stated form and widen the statement of form to fit the wider range of entries you expect could happen.

If that would be "bad" (not being the currently stated entries), their formatted results should easily stand out when a supervisor examines them and lead to their correction.

Comment: This turns `12345` into `00 12345` when the OP wants `12 345` I think.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).